# Why does dir.create give cannot create dir 'results', reason 'No such file or directory'?

Tags: r

After run my analysis I tried to create a new folder and save my results. I got the message:

> dir.create("results")
> Warning message:
> In dir.create("results") :
> cannot create dir 'results', reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Have you done a quick check of `getwd()` to make sure that your working directory is a place where you can read/write?

Comment: As an addition to @Dan Y's comment: You cannot create new directories in directories that don't exist (no recursive directory creation). As pointed out, if ``dir.exists(getwd())`` is ``FALSE`` you have to create ``dir.create(getwd()) first.

Comment: Guys thanks for the comments. I've checked. > getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/alima/Documents"
> dir.exists(getwd())
[1] TRUE
>

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to create a new nested directory, e.g. `"D:/mytest/myresults"`, wehre `D:/mytest` needs to be created as well as the subdirectory `/myresults`, `dir.create()` will **not work** when you use:

```
dir.create("D:/mytest/myresults")
```

Becasue `"D:/mytest"` does not exist, you cannot create `"D:/mytest/myresults"` and you will receive the warning:

> In dir.create("D:/mytest/myresults") :   cannot create dir
> 'D:\mytest\myresults', reason 'No such file or directory'

**Use `recursive = TRUE` insted:**

```
dir.create("D:/mytest/myresults", recursive = TRUE)
```

Using `recursive = TRUE` is equivalent to creating the base directory first and the subdirectory after that, like:

```
dir.create("D:/mytest")
dir.create("D:/mytest/myresults")
```